# proper way to use if/else statement with windows scroll

Tags: jquery

i am designing a webpage, there are two div;s at the top of the page.I want when i scroll grater than 50px the second div move to the top of the page and become fixed so the rest of the page scrolls underneath it. this is what i have so far, any help will be welcome.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {    
        $('#navigation').css("position", "fixed");
    }
    else{
        if($(window).scrollTop() < 50) {     
    $('#navigation').css("position", "none")
    }
    }
});
```

});

```
CSS
#page-header
{ height:120px;
background:none;
border:1px solid #000; position: }

#navigation
{ width:100%;
height:60px;
border:1px solid #f00; }

HTML
<div id="page-header" >
            <div id="toggle-menu"><a class="toggle-nav" href="#">&#9776;&nbsp;<span>MENU</span></a></div>
                <div id="search-page"><a href="#"><h1>SEARCH</h1></a></div>
            <div id="login-page"><a href="#"><h1>LOGIN</h1></a></div>


       <div id="navigation" class="fixed_header">
            <div id="caption"><h1>Sophiscated web</h1></div>
                <div id="menu">
                        <ul id="nav">
                            <li class="current-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Support</a></li> 
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        </ul>  
                </div><!-- menu Ends Here -->
```

Comment: why you want to use `if($(window).scrollTop() < 50) {` when the `else` part itself depicts that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the top value also along with position like

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
  $('#navigation').toggleClass("fixed", $(window).scrollTop() > 50);
});
```

```css
#page-header {
    height:120px;
    background:none;
    border:1px solid #000;
    position:
}
#navigation {
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    border:1px solid #f00;
}
#navigation.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

body{min-height: 800px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-header" >
    <div id="toggle-menu"><a class="toggle-nav" href="#">&#9776;&nbsp;<span>MENU</span></a></div>
    <div id="search-page"><a href="#"><h1>SEARCH</h1></a></div>
    <div id="login-page"><a href="#"><h1>LOGIN</h1></a></div>


    <div id="navigation" class="fixed_header">
        <div id="caption"><h1>Sophiscated web</h1></div>
        <div id="menu">
            <ul id="nav">
                <li class="current-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Support</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>  
        </div><!-- menu Ends Here -->
```

Comment: hey just a follow up. i have increased the scroll Top distance to 200px, is there a way to add say 1000ms timing to the div when it scrolls back down?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, I would add a class based on whether the desired scroll position has been reached like so:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
  // This adds the class 'sticky' to the #navigation div if 
  // $(window).scrollTop() > 50 is true
  $('#navigation').toggleClass('sticky', $(window).scrollTop() > 50);
});
```

However, I would improve upon this by not hard coding `50`, I would dynamically get the offset of the heading from the top of the page and use this instead:

```
var headerOffset = $('#caption').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function () {
  $('#navigation').toggleClass('sticky', $(window).scrollTop() > headerOffset);
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w58omkga/